# javamail mark gmail message as read

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Note: added after answer: 
Thanks.. Yeah I had tried the Flag.SEEN to true and saveChanges.. I also had read getContent marks it read. I tried using it in the for statement that loops through the messages. But I got the messages again from the folder anyways in the next loop. I was assuming the folder was live, so grabbing the content, then grabbing the messages again from the folder with the filter to not get any seen should work, but I was still getting the same message. I could try closing the folder and reopen as a test to see if it's marked. Also if I go over to my client and click the message, then my code stops seeing it even in the loop, so I was hoping to do the same in the code.

original:
I'm using javamail to get email from a gmail account, it's working great, when I get the message I'd like to mark it as read, can anyone give me some direction? Here is my current code:

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", eUserName, ePassWord);
        // Get folder
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        if (folder == null || !folder.exists()) {
            return null;
        }
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // Only pull unread
        FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
        Message messages[]; // = folder.search(ft);

        for(int x = 0; x < timeOutInSeconds; x++) {
            log.reportMessage("looking for emails");
            try {
                folder.getMessages();
                messages = folder.search(ft);

                if (messages.length > 0) {
                    for (Message message : messages) {
                        //log.reportMessage("found message: should not see again, marking read");
                        // want to mark as read

                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {

            }
        }

        // Close connection
        folder.close(false);
        store.close();
        return null;

    }
    catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {

        return null;
    }
    catch (MessagingException ex) {

        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, you can't mark a message as read if you are using a POP3 server - the POP3 protocol doesn't support that. However, the IMAP v4 protocol does.

You might think the way to do this is to get the message, set the `Flags.Flag.SEEN` flag to true, and then call `message.saveChanges()`. Oddly, this is not the case.

Instead, the JavaMail API Design Specification, Chapter 4, section "The Flags Class" states that the `SEEN` flag is implicitly set when the contents of a message are retrieved. So, to mark a message as read, you can use the following code:

```
myImapFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
myImapFolder.getMessage(myMsgID).getContent();
myImapFolder.close(false);
```

Or another way is to use the MimeMessage copy constructor, ie:

```
MimeMessage source = (MimeMessage) folder.getMessage(1)
MimeMessage copy = new MimeMessage(source);
```

When you construct the copy, the seen flag is implicitly set for the message referred to by source.

Comment: Ok, after looking at your code again i noticed you use Folder.READ_WRITE and I was using READ_ONLY. As soon as I changed that it worked as expected. thanks

Comment: So is there no way to make it behave such that messages are not marked as SEEN unless explicitly marked as such?

I am dealing with bad connection and sometimes connection drops while attachments are downloading.  And since .getcontent has already been called while this is happening, there I need to make sure its not marked as UNSEEN.

Comment: Note that this method has an overhead of downloading the entire message just to make it marked as SEEN.

Comment: `getContent()` _will not_ mark message as read if it's a MIME message, at least in IMAP I work with. This should not be the accepted answer, use Shloim's or James Vornhagen's one. And remember to test all possible cases because every IMAP implementation is different.

Answer (score 44):

One liner that will do it WITHOUT downloading the entire message:

single message:

```
folder.setFlags(new Message[] {message}, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);
```

all messages:

```
folder.setFlags(messages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);
```

Other methods of calling `getContent()` or creating a copy with `new MimeMessage(original)` cause the client to download the entire message, and creates a **huge** performance hit.

Note that the inbox must be opened for READ_WRITE:

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

Comment: This will do it without downloading the entire message. It works only on imap

Comment: This worked for me. Just had to switch to read-write mode like this: `emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);`

Answer (score 4):

Well this post is old but the easiest solution hasn´t been posted yet.

You are accessing the Message. 
message.setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);

Comment: This updates the local copy, it will not update the message in the inbox.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Message message : messages) {
                    message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN,true);
                }
```

**and** **change the below line**

`folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);`

**to this**

**`folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);`**

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider having a `public static int max_message_number`, and storing in it the `message[i].getMessageNumber();` as soon as you read a message. Then before reading any message just check if the `max_message_number < message[i].getmessageNumber()`. If true then don't print this message (as it has been already read)

Answer (score 0):

message.setFlag( Flag.SEEN,true ) give "cannot find symbol"
message.setFlag( Flags.Flag.SEEN,true ) seems good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a for loop to read or check a mail one by one, the code can be as follows to mark a gmail message as read:

```
    Message[] unreadMessages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
            for (int q = 0; q < unreadMessages.length; q++) {

              unreadMessages[q].setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);

            }
```

What this code does is that it makes it unread one by one.

And also folder/inbox needs to be READ_WRITE, instead of READ_ONLY:

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

Comment: For loop is too expensive. The server can handle it in a single command: `folder.setFlags(unreadMessages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

head over to the gmail settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP

from the dropdown of **When messages are accessed with POP**
select *mark Gmail's copy as read* and save the changes

Answer (score 0):

To mark the mail as read, you just have to call the `mailmessage.getContent()` method.
Whether you use IMAP or POP, calling that method on a specific mail mark it as Read

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do that is set the folder to be read or written into or from. Means like this...

```
    Folder inbox = null;
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

the Folder class should be imported.