# How do I ensure that the SEEN flag on an IMAP email message is not automatically marked as SEEN on doing getContent

Tags: imap, jakarta-mail

I am dealing with a bad connection to an external IMAP server.  I need my application to download messages from this mail server periodically.  On many occasions, my code has already downloaded message using javamail and has executed message.getContent and is then processing individual body parts (attachments).  While it is in the process of doing this, the connection can drop.

I need to thus make sure that messages are not marked as SEEN automatically on doing message.getContent, which is how Javamail behaves, as described in this reply here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7679091/303106

Is there any way to make sure messages that were not downloaded are not marked as SEEN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Message msg = ...;
((IMAPMessage)msg).setPeek(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the `BODY.PEEK` instead of just `BODY` when fetching the data, and/or use `EXAMINE` instead of `SELECT` to open a mailbox. I'll leave it as an excercise to the reader to read the javamail's documentation to see how these options relate to the features provided by the havamail.

Comment: Thanks.  At least I know there is a way.  I will look into javamail documentation.  It is not very well documented but I see some methods in API docs which seem relevant.